# Intermittent connection failures when querying Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

We have a Rails API that queries Elasticsearch via the elasticsearch-rails gem. At around 10:30 yesterday morning, we started getting a bunch of Faraday::ConnectionFailed errors. They don't happen every time, but they've been happening a bunch. Looking at our Elasticsearch console, I can see that our CPU, memory, and disk usage are all within healthy limits (no more than 50% capacity). We haven't made any code/infrastructure changes in a week, so I'm a little lost on how to debug this properly.

We've tried replacing the elasticsearch-rails gem with elasticsearch-ruby client and are still getting ConnectionFailed errors, though these ones are slightly different/more verbose:

```
[Faraday::ConnectionFailed] Failed to open TCP connection to [REDACTED].eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:443 (execution expired) 
{:scheme=>"https", :user=>"elastic", :password=><REDACTED>, :host=>"[REDACTED].eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com", :port=>443, :protocol=>"https"}

[Faraday::ConnectionFailed] Attempt 1 connecting to 
{:scheme=>"https", :user=>"elastic", :password=><REDACTED>, :host=>"[REDACTED].eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com", :port=>443, :protocol=>"https"}
```

We believe the bug is related to how our containers in GCP connect to ElasticCloud, because when we connect to our Elastic instances from a local machine we don't see the errors. We only get these errors when querying Elasticsearch from our GCP cloud containers. Any help/thoughts are appreciated as we're not sure how to debug next.